# Spring @Scheduled com transação interna disparando erro de propagation

Tags: java, spring, transações, scheduler

Estou tentando executar um serviço que se baseia na execução pela cron com a anotação `@Scheduled`, mas toda vez que uma transação de banco de dados precisa ser aberta dentro do metodo anotado com `@Scheduled` recebo o erro informado abaixo:

```
@Service
public class Tasks{

    @Autowired
    private OpenServiceRepository openServiceRepository;

    /*
     * Metodo que fica responsavel por verificar todos os faturamentos no qual
     * a data da venda seja a data atual menos 395 dias com os items sendo de
     * credito e nao gerando debito
     * 
     */
    @Scheduled(cron="*/5 * * * * ?")
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
    public void demoServiceMethod(){
        long count = openServiceRepository.count();
        System.out.println("O numero de Serviços em aberto é: " + count);
    }
}
```

Abaixo segue o stacktrace completo:

```
 15:34:25.005 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
    org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: No existing transaction found for transaction marked with propagation 'mandatory'
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:359) ~[spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:420) ~[spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:257) ~[spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644) ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at br.com.joocebox.quartz.Tasks$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d0429f10.demoServiceMethod(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) ~[spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) [spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que a implementação de `@Transactional` por padrão usa um *proxy*. Quando você anota o mesmo método com uma anotação como `@Scheduled` ela não passa por nenhum *proxy* e assim o Spring não tem como interceptar as chamadas para controlar transações.

#### Solução

Mova o `demoService` para uma outra classe mantendo a anotação `Transacional` nesse segundo nível:

```
@Service
public class DemoService {
    @Autowired
    private OpenServiceRepository openServiceRepository;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void demoServiceMethod(){
        long count = openServiceRepository.count();
        System.out.println("O numero de Serviços em aberto é: " + count);
    }
}
```

E use sua nova classe dentro do erviço de *scheduling*:

```
@Service
public class Tasks {   
    @Autowired
    private DemoService demoService;

    @Scheduled(cron="*/5 * * * * ?")
    public void fireDemoService(){
        demoService.demoServiceMethod();
        System.out.println("O numero de Serviços em aberto é: " + count);
    }
}
```

Dessa forma a *task* passará pelo *proxy* na chamada de `demoServiceMethod` e a transação será aberta como esperado.

Adicionalmente, caso você realmente precise de transações dentro da mesma classe, uma opção é habilitar *weaving* em tempo de compilação ou *loading* (e.g., usando: [`@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html) e [@EnableLoadTimeWeaving](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/EnableLoadTimeWeaving.html))

---

### Referências:

- [SOen - Spring3 's @Transactional @Scheduled not committed to DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5443876/664577)
- [Spring Framework reference - Using @Transactional](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)
- [Load-time weaving with AspectJ in the Spring Framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw-spring)
- [Spring transactions on non-public methods with load-time weaving](http://howtodoinjava.com/2015/06/29/spring-transactions-on-non-public-methods-with-load-time-weaving/)